# Prompt to change userid for logon when site not shared

Tags: 2013, access-denied, sso

For SharePoint 2013 I have two accounts, my primary system logon and my administration logon. When accessing https://spadmin.internal.domain/ with IE11 the SSO automatically tries to logon using my primary system logon which fails throwing a message of 'Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you'. There is nothing else on the page.

How can I logon using my admin account when it doesn't ask for my username and password and does not have an option to switch user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open IE11 and follow below steps:

1. Go to **Tools** >> **Internet Options**(last option) >> **Security** tab(2nd tab) >> click **Custom level** button.
2. Scroll down in **Settings** pane.
3. In the end, there is **User Authentication logon**, select **Prompt for user name and password**.
4. Click **OK** button. (Do it in both windows)
5. **Restart** IE11.

And then try to access your url.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Also: added website to Internet Options > Trusted Sites and set this to Prompt to username and password and it worked. Unsure how this is different to using closeConnection.aspx or run as. This solves the first problem allowing for identifying the other issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are two workaround for this problem.

1. Start Internet Explorer or other browser by using the Run as different user
   option and use your admin account as login.
2. Access the SharePoint site by using the following URL:

https://spadmin.internal.domain/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

Comment: Tried #1 - did not work. Same error. It did allow for logging in as the alternate account.

Tried #2 - Opened new IE11 window, SSO automatically logged in with LAN account, changed to a URL with _layouts, set URL to `_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true` and it asked for a new logon name and password. Entered admin account username and password and saw the same error. 

Alternatively, I used Google Chrome with the spadmin url. It asked for a username and password and works.

IE11? Internal settings or configuration? Mutual distrust of Microsoft products?