# Try to remove the saved Window credential but not found in Manage Credentials

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, windows-authentication, ie

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise edition. One of our user is doing UAT on test environment. He is using a computer joined production domain (prod.com), browse to our test SharePoint farm (http://test.com/sites/test/) to test.

When he browse the test site first time, a login prompt so he type in login (test/userA) and the password. He can login successfully. Later he want to login as another user (test/userB) but he found IE have saved his credential. The login prompt never show up again when he type in the site URL. He is always login as userA.

I suggest him remove his saved credential with `Start, Control Panel, User Accounts, then click Manage Credentials`. But he found nothing is saved.

I wonder what kind of setup can save the test domain credential? The user is using Win7 and IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2013 always use the credentials of pc, whom you login.

But if you hack the url then you ll get the login prompt.

```
http://<site URL>/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

Or Launch Ie as different user. Check this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752600

Comment: The credential of PC is PROD/someuser not TEST/userA. Then is why I don't understand....

Comment: What authentication method u are using in sharepoint, with ntlm I don't think it can happen...but with adfs or fba it is possible

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint uses Claims based authentication and thusly will generate a Windows Claim cookie. Clearing your cookie cache should work. Also, starting IE with the `-nomerge` switch should make it start fresh each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try steps for IE mentioned in below url for prompting for credentials every time you visit site.

[Prompt to change userid for logon when site not shared](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171833/prompt-to-change-userid-for-logon-when-site-not-shared/171843#171843)